# Jersey web service hangs when returning pojo from GET request

Tags: java, rest, jersey, weblogic

I have set up a jax-rs web service using Jersey 1.9 on Oracle WebLogic 11g. My web service has two web methods:

```
    @Path("{lid}/name")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getName(@PathParam("ebid") long ebid, @PathParam("lid") long lid)
    {
        System.out.println("LocationService.getName");
        LocationLocalSession ejb = EJBLookup.getLocationLocalSession();
        LocationVO location = ejb.getLocationInfo(ebid, lid);
        System.out.println("return location name: " + location.getLocationName());

        return location.getLocationName();
    }
```

The first one (above) works exactly as expected, with no issue.  It retrieves a Location object via an EJB, and returns that location object's name in plain text. I setup this method just to test if the web service was working at all. I really only care about the second method.

Below, is the second web method. It does almost the same as the first. It retrieves a location object via an EJB, but returns the entire location object, not just the name, as JSON. When I make a call to this method (ajax or web browser directly), the method executes, it retrieves the location object, prints the print statements to the app server log as expected, but never return a response, it just hangs indefinitely.

```
@Path("{lid}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public LocationVO get(@PathParam("ebid") long ebid, @PathParam("lid") long lid)
{
    System.out.println("LocationService.get");
    LocationLocalSession ejb = EJBLookup.getLocationLocalSession();
    LocationVO location = ejb.getLocationInfo(ebid, lid);
    System.out.println("return location: " + location.getLocationName());
    return location;
}
```

Eventually the request times out due to no response, and I end up with a stuck thread in WebLogic. Does anyone have any clue why this method won't return a response? I can make as many methods as I want that return String/plain text and they always work, but as soon as i try to return an object as JSON, it hangs every time. Here is my Jersey config in web.xml in case it can provide any clues:

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>JAX-RS Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>gis.ws.ServiceApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks

EDIT: adding LocationVO

```
public class LocationVO implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //The Database Fields variable should be used in SQL queries
    public static final String LOCATION_DATABASE_FIELDS = 
            "LOCATION.LOCATION_ID LOCATION__LOCATION_ID, "+
            "LOCATION.EVENT_BOARD_ID LOCATION__EVENT_BOARD_ID, " +                              
            "LOCATION.LOCATION_NAME LOCATION__LOCATION_NAME, " +
            "LOCATION.ADDRESS LOCATION__ADDRESS, "+
            "LOCATION.CITY LOCATION__CITY, "+
            "LOCATION.STATE LOCATION__STATE, "+
            "LOCATION.ZIPCODE LOCATION__ZIPCODE, "+
            "LOCATION.COUNTRY LOCATION__COUNTRY, "+
            "LOCATION.PHONE LOCATION__PHONE, "+
            "LOCATION.MAP_GRID LOCATION__MAP_GRID, "+
            "LOCATION.COMMENTS LOCATION__COMMENTS, "+
            "LOCATION.CREATED_BY LOCATION__CREATED_BY, "+
            "LOCATION.CREATED_DATE LOCATION__CREATED_DATE ";

    private long    locationId   = 0l;
    private long    eventBoardId = 0l;
    private String  locationName = null;
    private String  address      = null;
    private String  city         = null;
    private String  state        = null;
    private String  zipcode      = null;
    private String  country      = null;
    private String  phone        = null;
    private String  mapGrid      = null;
    private String  comments     = null;
    private long    createdBy    = 0l;
    private Date    createdDate  = null;
    private String  displayName  = null;

    //this field is not part of the database:
    private long    requestor    = 0l;

    public LocationVO()
    {}

    public  long   getLocationId()                      {return this.locationId;}
    public  void   setLocationId(long locationId)       {this.locationId = locationId;}

    public  long   getEventBoardId()                    {return this.eventBoardId;}
    public  void   setEventBoardId(long eventBoardId)   {this.eventBoardId = eventBoardId;}

    public  String getLocationName()                    {return this.locationName;}
    public  void   setLocationName(String locationName) {this.locationName = StringUtilities.safeTrim(locationName);}

    public  String getAddress()                         {return this.address;}
    public  void   setAddress(String address)           {this.address = StringUtilities.safeTrim(address);}

    public  String getCity()                            {return this.city; }
    public  void   setCity (String city)                {this.city  = StringUtilities.safeTrim(city);}

    public  String getState()                           {return this.state; }
    public  void   setState(String state)               {this.state = StringUtilities.safeTrim(state);}

    public  String getZipcode ()                        {return this.zipcode; }
    public  void   setZipcode (String zipcode)          {this.zipcode = StringUtilities.safeTrim(zipcode);}

    public  String getCountry ()                        {return this.country; }
    public  void   setCountry (String country)          {this.country = StringUtilities.safeTrim(country);}

    public  String getPhone()                           {return this.phone;}
    public  void   setPhone(String phone)               {this.phone = StringUtilities.safeTrim(phone);}

    public  String getMapGrid()                         {return this.mapGrid;}
    public  void   setMapGrid(String mapGrid)           {this.mapGrid = StringUtilities.safeTrim(mapGrid);}

    public  String getComments()                        {return this.comments;}
    public  void   setComments(String comments)         {this.comments = StringUtilities.safeTrim(comments);}

    public  long   getCreatedBy()                       {return this.createdBy;}
    public  void   setCreatedBy(long createdBy)         {this.createdBy = createdBy;}

    public  Date   getCreatedDate()                     {return this.createdDate;}
    public  void   setCreatedDate(Date createdDate)     {this.createdDate = createdDate;}

    public  long   getRequestor()                       {return this.requestor;}
    public  void   setRequestor(long requestor)         {this.requestor = requestor;}

    public  String getDisplayName()                     {return this.displayName;}
    public  void   setDisplayName(String displayName)   {this.displayName = StringUtilities.safeTrim(displayName);}

    public  boolean getValid() 
    {
        return (this.locationName != null && this.locationName.length() > 0)
         || (this.address != null && this.address.length() > 0)
         || (this.city != null  && this.city.length() > 0);
    }

    public LocationVO copy()
    {
        LocationVO copy = new LocationVO();

        copy.locationId   = this.locationId;
        copy.eventBoardId = this.eventBoardId;
        copy.locationName = this.locationName;
        copy.address      = this.address;
        copy.city         = this.city;
        copy.state        = this.state;
        copy.zipcode      = this.zipcode;
        copy.country      = this.country;
        copy.phone        = this.phone;
        copy.mapGrid      = this.mapGrid;
        copy.comments     = this.comments;
        copy.createdBy    = this.createdBy;
        copy.createdDate  = this.createdDate;
        copy.displayName  = this.displayName;

        return copy;
    }

    public String getLocationForDisplayAsHtml()
    {
        StringBuffer addressBlock = new StringBuffer();

        if (locationName != null)
        { 
            addressBlock.append(locationName);
            if (address != null || city != null || state != null  || zipcode != null  || country != null || phone != null || mapGrid != null)
                addressBlock.append("<br/>");
            else return addressBlock.toString();
        }


        if (address != null)
        { 
            addressBlock.append(address);
            if (city != null || state != null  || zipcode != null  || country != null || phone != null || mapGrid != null)
                addressBlock.append("<br/>");
            else return addressBlock.toString();
        }

        if (city != null)
        {
            addressBlock.append(city);
            if (state != null)
            {
                addressBlock.append(",&nbsp;"+state);
            }
            addressBlock.append("&nbsp;");

        }
        else if (state != null)
        {
            addressBlock.append(state +"&nbsp;");
        }   

        if (zipcode != null) addressBlock.append(zipcode);

        if ((city != null || state != null  || zipcode != null)  && country != null || phone != null || mapGrid != null)
            addressBlock.append("<br/>");

        if (country != null) addressBlock.append(country +"&nbsp;");
        if (phone != null) addressBlock.append(phone +"&nbsp;");
        if (mapGrid != null) addressBlock.append(mapGrid);

        return addressBlock.toString();
    }

    public String getLocationForDisplayAsHtml(String highlight)
    {
      return this.getLocationForDisplayAsHtml().replaceAll(highlight,"<span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>"+highlight+"</span>");
    }


    /**
     * This method returns a String representation of this object for audit trail purposes.
     */
    public String asString()
    {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        boolean first = true;

        if(this.locationName != null)
        {
            if (!first) result.append(", ");
            result.append(this.locationName);
            first = false;
        }
        if(this.address != null)
        {
            if (!first) result.append(", ");
            result.append(this.address);
            first = false;
        }
        if(this.city != null)
        {
            if (!first) result.append(", ");
            result.append(this.city);
            first = false;
        }
        if(this.state != null)
        {
            if (!first) result.append(", ");
            result.append(this.state);
            first = false;
        }
        if(this.zipcode != null)
        {
            if (!first) result.append(", ");
            result.append(this.zipcode);
            first = false;
        }
        if(this.country != null)
        {
            if (!first) result.append(", ");
            result.append(this.country);
            first = false;
        }
        if(this.mapGrid != null)
        {
            if (!first) result.append(", ");
            result.append(this.mapGrid);
            first = false;
        }

        return result.toString();
    }


    /**
     * This method returns a String representation of this object for audit trail purposes.
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(this.locationId +",");

        if(this.eventBoardId != 0l)   result.append(this.eventBoardId +",");
        if(this.locationName != null) result.append(this.locationName +",");
        if(this.address != null)      result.append(this.address +",");
        if(this.city != null)         result.append(this.city +",");
        if(this.state != null)        result.append(this.state +",");
        if(this.zipcode != null)      result.append(this.zipcode +",");
        if(this.country != null)      result.append(this.country +",");
        if(this.mapGrid != null)      result.append(this.mapGrid +",");
        if(this.comments != null)     result.append(this.comments +",");
        if(this.createdBy != 0l)      result.append(this.createdBy +",");
        if(this.createdDate != null)  result.append(this.createdDate +",");
        if(this.displayName != null)  result.append(this.displayName +",");

        if(result.length() > Constants.AUDIT_TRAIL_DATA_STORAGE_FIELD_LENGTH)
            return result.toString().substring(0, Constants.AUDIT_TRAIL_DATA_STORAGE_FIELD_LENGTH);
        else
            return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What JSON serializer are you using? Jackson? What is the structure of `LocationV0` ?

Comment: The documentation I've read on setting this up says Jersey utilizes Jackson for this. The only thing supposedly required is the init-param in the web.xml: com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature.

Comment: LocationVO is just a pojo.  No lookups or outside references, just properties with getters and setters.

Comment: how far does your code run before it lags? does it print "return location.." to your console?

Comment: Yes, even the last printout right before the return statement prints, indicating that the location object was retrieved.

Comment: does LocationVO implement Serializable?

Comment: Yep, just added LocationVO code for reference in the question

Comment: Please see my updated answer and let me know if it solves it for you

Answer (score 3):

Try with two basic REST resources to test your configurations.
If both them fail it's something in Oracle WebLogic.

```
@Path("test1")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public LocationVO test1()
{
    LocationVO location = new LocationVO();
    location.setLocationName("somewhere");
    return location;
}

@Path("test2")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject test2()
{
    return new JSONObject().put("test2", "works");  
}
```

Comment: did you found the problem?

Comment: I narrowed it down but not solved. WebLogic hangs with a stuck thread every time it tries to serialize a POJO to JSON on a GET, and also when deserializing JSON to POJO on PUT or POST. I think there is something wrong with com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature.

Answer (score 1):

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/json.html

To be able to map POJO correctly, the parser will have to know how to handle the object. Adding @XmlRootElement to the object lets the parser know where to start.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class LocationVO implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

P.S
Another tip is to use a Logger, not System.out.println() because it will print logg also when the application is deployed to a server. "sysout" will only print to your console.

Comment: Great suggestion, I missed that, but unfortunately the same problem persists even after adding the XmlRootElement annotation.